# Loop through range of cells and change color if a value is in that range more then 3 times

Tags: vba, excel

I have one column with different numbers in it. My code is sorting them and shall check how often the same number appears in that column. If one value appears more than 3 times, it should color all rows containing that value, else the rows should be deleted.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub mySub10()

Dim wsTEMP As Worksheet
Dim wsSPECIAL As Worksheet
Dim wsTEMPLrow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Set wsTEMP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
Set wsSPECIAL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spezial")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wsTEMPLrow = Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & Worksheets("Temp").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With wsTEMP

  .Columns("A:Q").Sort Key1:=.Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

For i = wsTEMPLrow To 5 Step -1
    Set rng = Range("A" & i)
    If Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 1, 12).Value And Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 2, 12).Value And Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 3, 12).Value And Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 4, 12).Value Then
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Range("A" & i - 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End If
Next

For i = wsTEMPLrow To 2 Step -1
    Set rng = Range("A" & i)
    If rng.Interior.ColorIndex <> 6 Then
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next        

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. First, add a `COUNTIF` formula in another column. This will reveal how many times each number appears in column A. Here's an example of this with a small dataset. The formula in cell B2 is `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15,A2)` and it's copied down manually -- or you can do this in VBA:

```
Range("B2:B15").Formula = "=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15, $A2)"
```

I applied conditional formatting to column A to highlight those values whose count is 3 or more.

[image]

Then you can delete those rows where the count is less than 3:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
Set r = Range("B2:B15")
For i = r.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    With r.Cells(i, 1)
        If .Value < 3 Then
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jean. Could you please let me know how I can implement the countif function for each cell in column R?
The sheet is created as a temporary sheet before and I don't want to put the formula in manually.

Comment: I guess you mean, how to do this using VBA? I have now added that at the top of my answer. If you want this in column R, just replace all B's with R's.

Comment: Corbett Thanks for your assistance. One more question: My code would be Range("R2:R" & Lrow).Formula = "=COUNTIF($L$2:$L$15, $L2)" How can I make $L$15 dynamically to match the Lrow as well?

Comment: Care to take a guess? :-)  It's pretty similar to what you did for column R on the left hand side of that assignment... If you find the answer above useful, please consider upvoting/accepting.

Comment: Corbett I used Range("R2:R" & Lrow).Formula = "=COUNTIF($L:$L, $L2)" and it works now. I already upvoted and now that I have found the answer, I can accept it as the answer :)

Comment: Great! I imagine this would work, too: `.Formula = "=COUNTIF($L$2:$L$" & Lrow & ", $L2)"`

Comment: Corbett Is there any way to speed up the performance for deleting the rows or could anyone think of some kind of workaround?? I have about 10k rows of data and it is terribly slow. It takes ages - about 20 minutes for the first 2k rows

Comment: I found a workaround for me. I ordered the data by the descending numbers and ran a for loop. When the condition .value > 3 wasn't met, I let the code select all the data below and delete it. That way is way quicker then looping through every row and deleting every single row.

Comment: Right, because your data is sorted... I missed that bit. Nice. Otherwise, you can certainly speed it up using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the top of your code. There are other tricks, too. Search this site and you'll find answers.

Comment: Disabling the Screenupdating was the first thing I did, without any reasonable effect. :)

Comment: @DEFCON123 Having 10k rows in Excel usually indicates that you are using it for something it was not designed to. Maybe using MS Access or a full-blown database (SQLite being a lightweight one) would be the best solution for you. In SQL (database query language, implemented by MS Access too), sorting, counting unique values and many other operations are simply done in just one query.

Comment: @Palec And that's why Excel has 1M rows available, up from 65k in 2003?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Capability of a program is not saying anything about supported use cases. Don’t know the design decision behind Big Table. But from what I am reading on MSDN, many performance tweaks have been done on Excel to cope with such a large grid. However my primary goal was not telling that Excel is inherently bad or slow. I wanted to show some alternatives that may be more suitable for more complex scenarios and bigger data.

Answer (score 6):

The highlighting part can be achieved using [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-HA102809768.aspx) and [`COUNTIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-function-HA102753077.aspx). Only deletion has to be done through VBA.

I assume the column with numbers is column `A`.

## `COUNTIF` counts number of occurrences

To count number of occurrences of a value in column `A`, just use this formula in first row of a column and fill the whole column with it:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A, A1)
```

`COUNTIF` counts all values in the specified range (first argument) that satisfy the condition given (second argument). `A:A` is the whole column `A`. Specifying cell reference as a condition to `COUNTIF` means that occurrences of the same value should be counted.

Now you can delete the column with `COUNTIF` formula as it was used just for demonstration of how `COUNTIF` works. It will not be needed anymore.

## Conditional formatting

Using the formula written above, it is possible to conditionally format cells with values repeating more than three times. By making the column references absolute, it is possible to format whole lines the same way as their first cell. Select the whole table, having the `A1` cell activated, and set conditional formatting with condition defined by the following formula:

```
COUNTIF($A:$A, $A1) > 3
```

Change 3 to any other constant if needed. E.g. using 1 applies the format on all duplicate values.

`$` before a part of an address is absolute addressing. `$A1` is the cell in column `A` in the same row as currently formatted cell (as the row number is still relative). For more info on cell addressing see [About cell and range references @ Excel support page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-cell-and-range-references-HP005198323.aspx).

## Applying the format from VBA

Using VBA you can apply the formatting like this:

```
Selection.Cells(1,1).Activate
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="COUNTIF($A:$A, $A1) > 3"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Use `Range("A:A").Select` to select the whole first column if not having done the selection otherwise. Use `Selection.FormatConditions.Delete` after selecting the range to get rid of the conditional formatting set previously. You may want to alter the format, too. The last line just sets the font color to color number 6 in the current palette. It is yellow in the default palette, which can be seen on [MS Graph VB reference page for ColorIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx).

See:

- [programming conditional formatting rules - excel vba @ MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/33c9eb1a-7786-4b49-b153-c16b6bf317d3/programming-conditional-formatting-rules-excel-vba?forum=exceldev)
- [Conditional Formatting using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9004712/2157640)

## Deletion of non-formatted rows

To delete the rows that are not formatted, loop through the cells, get cell’s color using `cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex` and call `cell.EntireRow.Delete` if it is not colored:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    With Selection.Cells(i, 1)
        If .DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> 6 Then
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: But this just check whether A1's value is there three times... What if some other value is there 3 times? Then I think the OP wants those to light up, too. Not to mention that the other rows don't get deleted...

Comment: That is exactly the point why I can't use it @Jean-FrançoisCorbett :-)

Comment: @simoco Done. Written from the top off my head, not having Excel here right now.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want, I slightly changed your code:

```
Sub mySub10()

    Dim wsTEMP As Worksheet
    Dim wsSPECIAL As Worksheet
    Dim wsTEMPLrow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wsTEMP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
    Set wsSPECIAL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spezial")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    wsTEMPLrow = Worksheets("Temp").Range("A" & Worksheets("Temp").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With wsTEMP

      .Columns("A:Q").Sort Key1:=.Range("L1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    For i = wsTEMPLrow To 5 Step -1
        Set rng = Range("A" & i)
        'this checks the two rows before the present one. If this is true, there are at least three rows with the value.
        If Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 1, 12).Value And Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i - 2, 12).Value Then
                'this way the three rows you know have the value will be colored as desired.
                Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Range("A" & i - 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Range("A" & i - 2).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Next

    For i = wsTEMPLrow To 2 Step -1
        Set rng = Range("A" & i)
        If rng.Interior.ColorIndex <> 6 Then
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

    End With

End Sub
```