# Conditional Formatting using VBA - For Exact Matched Words

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

You commented on on the following page about ***Conditional Formatting using VBA*** -

[Conditional Formatting using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004712/conditional-formatting-using-vba/25497045#25497045)

> You don't need a loop for this. You can just add a new FormatCondition
>   to your range object.

```
lLow = 90000
lHigh = 100000

Set rng = Range("K8:K207")
rng.FormatConditions.Delete  ' delete any pre-existing formatting

' add greater than condition
With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=" & lHigh)
     .Interior.Color = rgbLimeGreen
End With

' add middle condition
With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & lLow, Formula2:="=" & lHigh)
   .Interior.Color = rgbGold
End With

' add less than condition
With rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=" & lLow)
   .Interior.Color = rgbRed
End With
```

Id like to know what it should be if you need an exact match that will be entered in the cell? Lets say this is what will be populated for example: ALPHA POSITION (2) - 1900Mhz.

How will it be written ? Is it like this?

```
Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=" ALPHA POSITION (2) - 1900Mhz)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add **"** char:

```
Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=""ALPHA POSITION (2) - 1900Mhz""")
```

To be accepted in VBA you need to insert double **""** otherwise VBA consider the single like finish of string...